# Can't connect google cloud cassandra nodes from laravel

Tags: laravel, cassandra, connection, cloud, virtual-machine

I am trying to connect to my google cloud vm-cassandra instance from my computer (using laravel framework).

I use this guide https://github.com/cubettech/lacassa to configure connection, but It says Class 'Cassandra' not found. Here is an image:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/HAg9L.jpg
In Connection.php it includes Cassandra class "use Cassandra"; 
I have no idea what I am doing wrong. Can someone help me?

Comment: do u use composer and class autoloading?

Comment: yes, I use composer.

I run composer require cubettech/lacassa
Then I added Cubettech\Lacassa\CassandraServiceProvider::class, to config/app.php

Comment: did u solve the problem?

Comment: Not yet. I have the same problem.

Answer (score 0):

You need to make sure that `datastax/php-driver` is installed. Check out the [installation instructions](https://github.com/datastax/php-driver) especially the part where you need to install the PECL extension

Comment: I try to run  sudo pecl install cassandra. 
It starts installing but at the and it displays error: 

configure: error: not supported. Driver version 2.7.0+ required (found )
ERROR: `/tmp/pear/temp/cassandra/configure --with-php-config=/usr/bin/php-config' failed

I included cassandra.so in php.ini. but it doen't work